# preg_match correct regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Since hours i try to find the correct regular expression. Let's say i have this:

```
$string = 'a=a.split("")';
```

and

```
$string = 'a=Ik(a,66)';
```

What i want to get as output is:

```
[1] => a
[2] => a
[3] => split
[4] => ""
```

and for the second one:

```
[1] => a
[2] => IK
[3] => a,66
```

I tried:

```
preg_match('#(.+)=(.+).(.+)[(](.+)[)]#', $string, $matches);
```

but this outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a=a.split("")
    [1] => a
    [2] => a.spl
    [3] => t
    [4] => ""
)
```

Why do i want this? I want to convert some javascript to PHP. For example:

```
function Hk(a) {
    a = a.split("");
    a = a.slice(1);
    a = a.reverse();
    a = Ik(a, 66);
    a = a.slice(2);
    a = a.reverse();
    a = Ik(a, 12);
    return a.join("")
}

function Ik(a, b) {
    var c = a[0];
    a[0] = a[b % a.length];
    a[b] = c;
    return a
}
```

**# Edit:** What i want is to convert it to PHP code and ouput it. I do not want to execute it.

For example the above javascript code should became something like this:

First function:

```
$a = str_split($a);
$a = array_slice($a, 1);
$a = array_reverse($a);
$a = self::Ik($a,66);
$a = array_slice($a, 2);
$a = array_reverse($a);
$a = self::Ik($a,12);
return implode("", $a);
```

second function:

```
$c = $a[0];
$a[0] = $a[$b%count($a)];
$a[$b] = $c;
return $a;
```

The `function` part itself is not imporant. I need only the logic in the function itself.

Comment: So you want to lex/parse some code into a token list?

Comment: What i basicly want is convert javascript code to php.

Comment: You are looking at a huge endeavor, you can't possibly do that with only one expression. A lexer is either built using a lexer generator and multiple regexes or you can build your own, but it's mighty hard. I already tried creating a php-lexer, but have yet to finish it and i have several hours of coding done.

Comment: You are looking at a lexer, parser, code converter and code generator!

Comment: It would not matter if it's one or more lines. The code iw ant to convert looks like in the example. It only uses "reverse", "slice" and "split" functions.

Comment: You'd need either 2 regex expressions or you'd regex to `a=Ik(a,66)` then check if one of the parts in the array for `a=a.split("")`, `explode()` at the point and regenerate said array.

Comment: Well the first function should be okay now with the solution from anubhava. But i have no idea how i could get the second one to php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to `consider preg_split`:

```
$arr = preg_split('/[=()]/', 'a=a.split("")', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => a.split
    [2] => ""
)

$arr = preg_split('/[=()]/', 'a=Ik(a,66)', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => Ik
    [2] => a,66
)
```

Comment: THanks that would be fine aswell. Du you have an idea hoe i could progress with the second javascript function? I mean how i could convert it to php? With the first one it's easier but with the second one it looks very hard. Thanks

Comment: I have just noticed your edited question. I submitted answer before you made edits, just to tokenize the given strings as you wanted. However to convert all the complex Javascript to PHP cannot be just done by regex alone. JS and PHP are different languages and have very different syntax which needs to be manually converted.

Comment: If you really have to (which I'd advise against), an associative array would work. i.e. `$a = array('reverse' => 'array_reverse')` and match the parts to the array.

Comment: Thanks as i said above the first javascript function should be fine with this example. If i combine that with some `if`. However i have no idea how can i progress the second one.

Comment: If you are talking about converting `function Ik(a, b)` then I believe that needs to manually converted to PHP.

Comment: I don't want to execute it in php. I just want to convert it and output it.

Comment: I misunderstood then. What should be output for `function Ik(a, b) {...}` function you're looking at.

Comment: I can tell you that this is not going to be easy. Not all Javascript functions have equivalent PHP function. Converting `a = a.split("");` to `$a = str_split($a);` is a different rule and conversion of  `return a.join("")` to `return implode("", $a);` needs different rule. There will be several hundred rules like that.

Comment: No the examples from above work fine i already did it manually.

Comment: Well i spent the last hours in progressing this stuff. I'm almost done. I'm just stuck at the second line in the second function. Is it possible to convert `a[0] = a[b % a.length];` to `$a[0] = $a[$b%count($a)];` with regex? I can't find a solution for that. Many thanks!

Comment: Sure let me take a shot at it.

Comment: Okayi already found it out. I did it with preg_replace. Now i just have another little problem. This `/([a-z])+\=([a-z])+\.(split|reverse|slice)+\(([^.]+)\)\;/` works fine with `a=a.split(h);` but it does not with `a=a.split();`. How can i fix that? Thank you

Comment: Oh that is wonderful. Feel free to share your work around so that I can edit my answer with it to benefit some future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

With php PCRE this should work for both patterns, even if you have different array elements filled, depending which pattern matches. I guess you can figure it our with testing the elements for nil etc.
This is done with an assertion and lookahead (do we have a dot, which results in one element more):

```
([^=]+)=(?(?=.+\.)([^.]+)\.([^.]+)|([^.]+))\((.+)\)
```

This is what comes up:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a=Ik(a,66)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ik
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => a,66
        )

)
```

and this one:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a=a.split("")
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => split
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => ""
        )

)
```

Hope this is of help ;)